# Copying from non-filtered rows to filtered-rows in excel

Tags: excel

I have a number of rows in one worksheet which doesn't have any filtered data all the data is visible.
I have another worksheet containing rows with filtered applied on it.

When I am trying to copy from non-filtered worksheet to filtered worksheet, the data is also pasted to non-visible cells in the filtered worksheet.

I have tried using goto special and then visible cells only but no success.

Comment: this is not possible, as can be seen the error you already got. You'll need to use formulas or vba to get the data into the filtered cells.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman could you explain the formula approach.

Comment: its hard to without seeing data, but you could potentially an `IF` statement to run against each row that simulates the filter, then perhaps a vlookup or index / match to grab data from the other sheet based on a common id (or several columns that create a common id).

Answer (score -1):

> 1) Copy the cells you want pasted. 2) Highlight range you want to
>   paste in to 3) Go to Home ribbon, Editing box, Find & Select. 4)
>   choose option - Go To Special 5) bottom right of the box choose
>   Visible Cells only. 6) now paste.

This should paste everything into just the visible cells and you don't have to run code as a macro.

Comment: Error: Copy area and paste area aren't the same size, because the hidden cells is also being considered in the paste area.